# How to print value of variable on PCB into String feature in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, silkscreen

I'd like to print value of *Revision* variable that can be set in [Project Options - Parameters](https://www.altium.com/documentation/16.0/display/ADES/WorkspaceManager_Dlg-ProjectPropertiesDialog_PageControl_Main_Parameters((Project+Options+-+Parameters))_AD) (not [Document Options](https://www.altium.com/documentation/16.0/display/ADES/Sch_Dlg-SheetOptions((Document+Options+(SCH)+))_AD) on Parameters tab) into silkscreen of PCB. How could I do this?

[image: trying to get value of parameter]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can print *schematic* document parameters on the PCB silkscreen. However, if you add it as a *project* parameter than you can use the syntax `'.ParameterName'` to print in silkscreen.

---

Project Parameter Setup:
[image]

---

PCB Silkscreen Setup:
[image]

---

Resulting Silkscreen:
[image]

Comment: I'd just like to mention here that you may see text **'.PCB_number'** while designing but it will render with value - you can see it in 3D view.

Comment: @mitjajez If you click the colored "Current Layer" box at the bottom of the editor next to your layers and switch to the "View Options" tab you can check the "Convert Special Strings" box under "Display Options" to show the rendered text real-time.

Answer (score 0):

There can be also name of Output set with Project Propertie like
`=Parameter+' other part of name'`